# Replacing words in a string with values from Dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, replace, .net-4.5

I have a simple `dictionary` like this:

`var fruitDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> {Apple,Fruit}, {Orange, Fruit}, {Spinach, Greens}`

and I have a string like

`var fruitString = Apple Orange Spinach Orange Apple Spinach`

How to replace all occurrences of the particular word in that sentence with the `matching-word` from the dictionary?

(i.e.) The above sentence should read `Fruit Fruit Greens Fruit Fruit Fruit` ?

Any ideas is much appreciated.

EDIT:

I tried something like this:

```
var outputString = string.Empty;
fruitString.ToArray().ToList().Foreach(item =>
{
if (fruitDictionary.ContainsKey(item))
{
 outputString = outputString + fruitDictionary[item];

}
```

Any optimal solution for this? The above code is not optimal because, it does `traversing` the entire-length of given array!

Comment: However you do it, I do not think you can do it without traversing the `fruitString`.

Comment: You will need to check each word in the dictionary against each word in the string at some point.  What magnitude of checking are we talking?  Thousands of entries in `fruitDictionary` and thousands of words in `fruitString`?

Comment: @mellamokb: good point. in my case, the size of the dictionary is small but the string size is longer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply:

```
var output = new StringBuilder(fruitString);

foreach (var kvp in fruitDictionary)
    output.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

var result = output.ToString();
```

This simply initializes a `StringBuilder` with your `fruitString`, and iterates over the `Dictionary`, replacing each key it finds with the value.

Comment: That works fine on a short string, on *really* long strings you have to consider that this is O(n*m), n being the number of dictionary entries, and m being the number of items in the string

Comment: Neat. My only concern would be performance for large dictionaries, where going through the whole dictionary, and searching the whole string for every entry, would be slow. A lookup-based approach would be faster. Fine for this case though!

Comment: @BrokenGlass True.. but I am struggling to think of any other way of doing it. At least with this solution there aren't strings being created at each iteration. Without knowing any more specific details about the use case it's hard to assume.

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

```
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fruitDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Apple", "Fruit"},
            {"Orange", "Fruit"},
            {"Spinach", "Greens"}
        };
        var fruitString = "Apple Orange Spinach Orange Apple Spinach";

        var result = string.Join(" ",
            fruitString.Split(' ').Select(i => fruitDictionary.ContainsKey(i) ? fruitDictionary[i] : i));
    }
}
```

This will be faster that find-and-replace based solutions if you have long strings and large dictionaries.

Comment: +1. thanks. But, i am worried about the ToList() parameter here: For really long strings, it has to first split, turn it to an array and then to a list and then perform a join.. it bothers me :(

Comment: Sorry, the ToList isn't necessary. I've edited the post, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed don't be worried - *measure* - implement both approaches and see what performs best

Answer (score 3):

Some smooth code for this:

```
var result = string.Join(" ", 
    string.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(
        i => fruitDictionary.ContainsKey(i) ? fruitDictionary[i] : i);
```

Should be `O(n*2m)` - where `n` is the traversal of string to split it and `2m` - one `m` for the traversal that does the word replacement via `Select()` and another `m` for the `string.Join` parameter of the results. Given that it is linear, it should scale decently.

To scale further, if your input string are not unique, cache the outputs of this method against the inputs in a `Dictionary<string, string>` - this will yield roughly `O(1)` for repeated inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by the [MSDN Replace MatchEvaluator Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(VS.71).aspx) and @Haney's answer
but with out the unrealistic 'Split'.

```
using System.Collections;

void Main()
{
    var args = new Dictionary<string, string> {
       {"Fruit1","Apple"}, 
       {"Fruit2", "Orange"}, 
       {"Greens", "Spinach"}
    };

    var output = Regex.Replace(
     "Hi, my Fav fruits are {Fruit1} and {Fruit2}. I like {Papaya}", 
     @"\{(\w+)\}", //replaces any text surrounded by { and }
     m => 
        {
            string value;
            return args.TryGetValue(m.Groups[1].Value, out value) ? value : "null";
        }
    );
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```